# How to keep the value in a field from the inputPassword helper in the Play framework?

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, passwords, form-helpers

Excuse me if the answer is obvious but whilst I know Java I am very new to Scala, the Play framework and general web app development.

I have taken on a project that has a view where you can set up some database connection details that includes fields such as database name, username, password etc. At present the code uses the Play input helper 'inputText' and so the password field shows the password in plain text. I need to fix this and so have changed it to use the 'inputPassword' helper however whenever I visit this page in my app to edit one of the other fields the password field has not been populated with the password so the user needs to re-enter it in order to save, I do not want to have to do this.

The password populated when it was an inputText helper so I can only assume that there's something in the inputPassword helper that stops the value from populating in the form, maybe it expects the password field to only be used when inputting a new one? Is there a way to override this and have it fill in the on screen form with the password so the user does not have to re-enter in order to change another field on the page?

This is the old version in my view

```
@inputField(form("password"), '_label -> "Password", '_labelwidth -> "2", 'class -> "form-control", '_type -> "password", '_single -> false)</code>
```

This is the new version

```
@inputPassword(form("password"), '_label -> "Password", '_labelwidth -> "2", 'class -> "form-control", '_single -> false, '_type -> "password")
```

I then have an the templates inputField.scala.html which contains `@helper.inputText(field, args:_*)` and the inputPassword.scala.html which contains `@helper.inputPassword(field, args:_*)`

I tried adding `'value -> form("password").value` to the parameters in the inputPassword version and whilst this displayed something in stars in the password field the credentials were incorrect so it cannot have been the correct information.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated, even if it is to just understand why inputText populates the field whereas inputPassword does not. The only other way I can think of to do this is possibly to have the password as a separate form on the same page and make it so the password entry is only mandatory when using the page for the initial set up of the database credentials and optional on the edit page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's really necessary to send password values back and forth for security reasons. As an internet user I've never seen form with filled password.

Regarding your case I see two options:

- Either separate password change into another form (but this is usually an option if you have more sophisticated password reset process, like two-step verification)
- Or apply the following password validation logic on the server: leave the password unchanged if it is empty

Comment: Thanks, I'll change the app then to use one of these methods.